# Internal Server Error- React App (Page not sending info to Backend)

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

Please see attached code. I have checked all the routes & package.json within client(fronend) folder and but it does not work.. any suggestions welcome.. i use Windows(11 home ed) and VS code IDE and Chrome browser but seem to be getting in one issues or ther other and either apps do not render, tranfer data or backend is within unreachable..

frondend package.json

```
  {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "antd": "^5.4.7",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }, "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

backend package.json

```
 {
  "name": "mern-expense",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css'
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Register from './pages/Register'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

routes

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const User = require('../models/userModel')

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await User.findOne({
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
    })
    if (result) {
      res.status(200).send(result)
    } else {
      res.status(500).json('Error')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error)
  }
})

router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newuser = new User(req.body)
    await newuser.save()
    res.send('User registered Successfully!')
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error)
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

register (fronend)

```
import React from 'react'
import '../resources/authentication.css'
import { Form, Input, message } from 'antd'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

function Register() {
  const onFinish = async (values) => {
    try {
      await axios.post('/api/users/register', values)
      message.success('registration successful...')
    } catch (error) {
      message.error('Something went wrong!')
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className='register'>
      <div className='row align-items-center justify-content-center w-100 h-100'>
        <div className='col-md-5'>
          <div className='lottie'>
            <lottie-player
              src='https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_06a6pf9i.json'
              background='transparent'
              speed='1'
              loop
              autoplay
            ></lottie-player>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='col-md-4'>
          <h1>Register -Bro</h1>
          <hr />
          <Form layout='vertical' onFinish={onFinish}>
            <Form.Item label='Name' name='name'>
              <Input />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label='Email' name='email'>
              <Input />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label='Password' name='password'>
              <Input type='password' />
            </Form.Item>

            <div className='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>
              <Link to='/login' className='to-login'>
                {' '}
                Already registered? -Login
              </Link>

              <button className='primary' type='submit'>
                Register
              </button>
            </div>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Register
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
require('dotenv').config()

const dbConnect = require('./dbConnect')

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

const userRoute = require('./routes/userRoutes')
app.use('/api/users', userRoute)

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello from Server...'))
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App is listening on port ${port}`))
```